# What is the benefit of turning off Gain Exp?

Tags: bravely-default

In the menus, under Tactics > Config > Difficulty, there is a setting for "Gain EXP" which I can turn Off or leave On. Since all my characters are at Level 99, there doesn't seem to be any point in gaining experience. Is there any benefit to turning off experience gain, such as additional JP or GP gain?

Comment: I doubt there is any. This is not the first JRPG to have this option either. It's just to provide an extra layer of challenge - to ensure you don't overlevel. But since you are at max level, this option becomes meaningless (this is all assumption based on past experience)>

Answer (score 1):

I had to use it when I was low on money, but already too high on XP for the game to be fun. Or when I was farming JP.

Sure, some people love to curbstomp bosses, but when you don t have any of the Eggs, just remade all your party for new job and need a lot of money, it s useful to turn of XP, farm JP and money, and when you have all the capacity you want and enought money to buy new shiny equipement, turn it back on and have a fair fight against the boss.

This become obsolete when you have Eggs or (as you and I now) are lvl.99.